# Enforce a where clause on particular column in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Can we write a wrapper around the django ORM so that every query should have a where clause?
Now, you cannot have an `all()` method which is fine.
For eg.
Let's assume we have `auth_user` table and `user_properties` table which has additional data about the user (and a foreign key from auth_user).
Here, if a developer want to get few rows from user_properties table, he has to provide the `user` or `user_id` column in `filter` query or it should give an exception.
Please write in comment if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want extend user mode, use OneToOne field to User model in you `user_properties` model, like this:

```
class UserProperty(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='properties')
    prop1 = models.CharField(...)
    prop2 = models.CharField(...)

prop1 = request.user.properties.prop1
```

Remember, you need create UserProperty when new user are created

Comment: This is not what I want to know. The table will definitely be created. What I want to know is this - A developer cannot use the all method and enforce him to use filter method with at least user in each query on UserProperty.